# Hiding content outside of background and show when scrolling

Tags: background, scroll, hide

Working URL:
http://webstage.co/scroll/stack.html

What I am trying to accomplish is to hide the content when it is outside of the background area (1280x800). I like the way the backgrounds are coming in when you scroll to a new section, but I want to hide the content until it gets into that 1280x800 viewport?  Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Bonus...It would be great if I could also hide the content under the top navigation once it scrolled up under it as well.  A guy can dream. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part you can add another div and target with css something like this:

```
 .viewport {
    width: 1280px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -640px;
    background: black;
    clip: rect(800px, 1280px, auto, auto);
}
```

Basically, set the background to the same color as the page background and use clip to only display the portion of the div that sits below your desired viewport area hiding the content outside the viewport area.

If you add content to the footer later you may need to tweak some z-index settings to make sure it sits on top of the viewport div.